# Unable to redirect browser traffic through VPN tunnel using plink.exe, badvpn_tun2socks.exe, and TAP device

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel

I am currently working on building a VPN application for Windows devices to tunnel all traffic through a dynamically forwarded port using plink.exe, badvpn_tun2socks.exe, and a TAP device. This setup allows me to forward both TCP and UDP ports effectively. However, I am facing an issue where none of my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) route their traffic through the VPN tunnel. I am seeking suggestions or alternative approaches to redirect browser traffic through the VPN tunnel without relying on browser extensions like FoxyProxy.

Here is a summary of my setup:

- Windows device: Windows operating system
- VPN tunneling tools: plink.exe and badvpn_tun2socks.exe
- TAP device: Used to establish the network interface for the VPN tunnel
- Other applications successfully route traffic through the VPN tunnel, including TCP and UDP traffic
- Browsers (Chrome, Firefox) are not redirecting their traffic through the VPN tunnel

I have tried the following approaches without success:

1. Exploring different programming languages:

   - I have experience with C# and C++ and have tried using libraries like SharpCap or writing filter drivers.
   - However, I would prefer to find a solution that does not involve writing low-level filter drivers.

Considering the above, I am open to any ideas, suggestions, or guidance to redirect browser traffic through the VPN tunnel. I am looking for alternative approaches or potential solutions to address this issue and ensure all traffic, including browser traffic, goes through the VPN tunnel.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise!